# eofbit not set with clear in C++98

Tags: c++, iostream, cin, getline, c++98

I have to make a program for homework that reads some user inputs using `std::cin` and `std::getline()`, but it is specified that the program should exit only when `EXIT` is typed.

I am currently trying to get <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> to do nothing, and multiple people have told me to use this snippet:

```cpp
if (std::cin.eof()) {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //some have told me to put nothing there, has not changed the behavior.
    continue;
}
```

The problem is, this does nothing when I test it. The `eofbit` flag is not reset, and `getline()` just continuously fails after that.

Here is my code:

```cpp
int main()
{
    PhoneBook phone;
    std::string input;
    while (true){
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        if (std::cin.eof()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            continue;
        }
        if (input == "ADD")
            phone.addContact();
        else if (input == "SEARCH")
            phone.search();
        else if (input == "EXIT")
            break;
        else
            std::cerr << "Invalid command, commands are ADD, SEARCH and EXIT" << std::endl;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

I have to code in C++98. I compiled with `clang++` using the following flags: `-Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c++98`

Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing this to fail?

I have tried editing what was inside the `ignore()` call, tried swapping the order between `clear()` and `ignore()`, verified the `eofbit` variable which is still set after a call to `clear()`.

Comment: If you reach the end of the "file", what makes you think there's more to read? What if the user wants to pipe to your program, or use redirection?

Comment: If you've hit the end of the file, there's nothing to `ignore`. `ignore` instantly fails and sets the EOF flag again.

Comment: I also find it kinda stupid that even if an eof is sent on the stdin the program must continue, but its what is asked in the subject, it isn't meant to be used for anyting else.

for `ignore` re-setting the EOF flag, removing `ignore` and checking the flag indicates it is still set just after the `clear()` call, the problem isn't coming from `ignore` it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. You havent reset `stdio` stream from `C` which is giving you a new `EOF`. Remove the sync and you should be good.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::string input;
    while (true){
        std::cin >> input;
        if (std::cin.eof()) {
            std::cout << "Ignore" << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');         
            continue;
        }
        if (input == "ADD")
            std::cout << "Adding"<< std::endl;
        else if (input == "SEARCH")
            std::cout << "Adding"<< std::endl;
        else if (input == "EXIT")
            break;
        else
            std::cerr << "Invalid command, commands are ADD, SEARCH and EXIT" << std::endl;
    }
    return (0);
}
```